# Making Elements not possible to manipulate Visibility

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, visibility

I have a ASP-WebForm-Application with several User-Rights.

In CodeBehind I am hiding some Elements if the specific Rights aren't given. But with F12 the User could manipulate the Code the get some Functionallity he isn't allowed to.

Are there any possibilities to hide Elements from CodeBehind, that they aren't make visible via Code-Manipulation? Something like destroying them completely in CodeBehind?

For example a Navigation based an List-Element, where I want to hide some Links:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <a>link 1<a/>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a>link 2<a/>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a>link 3<a/> // Has to be hidden by some conditions
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Hope someone could help me!

Comment: No you can't. And if you find a way to do so i would consider the browser you did it in as broken and would search for a replacement. If you want to hide something from the user don't send it to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `asp:PlaceHolder` or the `asp:Panel` and warp your content and make it visible or not.

Alternative you can add on the element the `runat="server" Visible="false"` and manipulate the visible.

Examples:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <a>link 1<a/>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a>link 2<a/>
    </li>
    <li runat="server" id="pnlToHide">
       <a>link 3<a/> // Has to be hidden by some conditions
    </li>
 </ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <a>link 1<a/>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a>link 2<a/>
    </li>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="pnlToHide2">
    <li>
       <a>link 3<a/> // Has to be hidden by some conditions
    </li>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
 </ul>
```

and on code behind

```
pnlToHide.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Okay. runat="server" AND Visible="false" is going not delivered to the Client?

Comment: @comidos yes is not going to render it, try it

Comment: what do you mean with "warp your content"?

Comment: that is not so easy. I use Controls from DevExpress with embedded buttons for example, which i can only hide via Visisble=false in CodeBehind but not set runat="server"

Comment: can you explain with a <li>-element for example?

Comment: @comidos Please add an full example of your code on your question.